# I have an issue while trying to use future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner and I am trying to learn Flutter.

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(
                'Go to the new page'
            ),
            onPressed: () {
             Future<bool?> pushFuture = Navigator.of(context).push<bool>(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return VideoScreen('Do you like the video?');
                },
              )
              );
             pushFuture.then((bool? answer) async {
               print('answer is: ${answer}');
               if(answer == true) {
                 print("He/She liked!!!");
                 return Future.value(true);
               }else{
                 Navigator.of(context).push<bool>(
                     MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder: (context) {
                         return VideoScreen('I wish you would liked it... Do you like the video?');
                       },
                     )
                 );
               }
             }).then((value) {
               if(value == true){
                 print('You liked it!!!');
               }
             });
```

I have a video screen and two answer buttons which are yes and no. I want to ask question again when they click on no and if they click yes in the second time. I want to print 'You liked it!!!' on the console screen. But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: I think you can just use single then `pushFuture.then(..here`

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Go to the new page'),
  onPressed: () async {
    bool? answer = await Navigator.of(context)
        .push<bool>(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return VideoScreen('Do you like the video?');
    }));

    if (answer == true) {
      print('You liked it!!!'); //same here
      print("He/She liked!!!");
      return Future.value(true);
    } else {
      final result = await Navigator.of(context)
          .push<bool>(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return VideoScreen(
            'I wish you would liked it... Do you like the video?');
      }));

      ///here another result
    }
  },
);
```